# Wordpress add_submenu_page issue

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

This is the base of my code. The idea is that when I click submit the form posts to the same page and runs my code inside the if statement. The problem is that when I hit submit I get a Wordpress error saying Cannot load tb-export. I have done a lot of Google searches and can not find a solution.

**Edit:** Here is the whole class. https://pastebin.com/i03m9a3x

**Edit Again:** I took the code outside of the class and simplified it and I am still getting the error. Below is the simplified code and **after I submit the form** I get the error **Cannot load export_display.**

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'tb_admin_menu');
function tb_admin_menu() {
  add_menu_page(
    'Table Builder',
    'Table Builder',
    'read',
    'i15-table-builder',
    '',
    'dashicons-screenoptions',
    21
  );

  add_submenu_page('i15-table-builder', 'Export', 'Export', 'manage_options', 'export_display', 'export_display');
}

    function export_display(){    
        if ($_POST['submit']) {
            $post_args = array(
                    'post_type' => $_POST['post_type'],
                    'post__in' => $_POST['ids']
                );

            $posts = get_posts($post_args);

          $count = 0;
                foreach ( $rtp_posts as $post ) {

                    $write_array[$count] = array(
                        'post_id'        => $post->ID,
                        'comment_status' => $post->comment_status,
                        'ping_status'    => $post->ping_status,
                        'post_author'    => $post->post_author,
                        'post_content'   => $post->post_content,
                        'post_excerpt'   => $post->post_excerpt,
                        'post_name'      => $post->post_name,
                        'post_parent'    => $post->post_parent,
                        'post_password'  => $post->post_password,
                        'post_status'    => $post->post_status,
                        'post_title'     => $post->post_title,
                        'post_type'      => $post->post_type,
                        'to_ping'        => $post->to_ping,
                        'menu_order'     => $post->menu_order
                    );

                    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post->post_type); // returns array of taxonomy names for post type, ex array("category", "post_tag");
                    foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
                        $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'slugs'));
                        $write_array[$count]['taxonomies'][$taxonomy] = $post_terms;
                    }

                    $post_meta_infos = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id=$post_id");
                    if (count($post_meta_infos)!=0) {
                        $sql_query = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) ";
              $countmetas = 0;
                        foreach ($post_meta_infos as $meta_info) {
                            $meta_key = $meta_info->meta_key;
                            if( $meta_key == '_wp_old_slug' ) continue;
                            $meta_value = addslashes($meta_info->meta_value);

                $write_array[$count]['metas'][$countmetas]['meta_key'] = $meta_key;
                            $write_array[$count]['metas'][$countmetas]['meta_value'] = $meta_value;
                            $countmetas++;
                        }
                    }

            $count++;
                }

          $write_array_encode = json_encode($write_array);

          header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=Table_Builder_Exported_Data.json');
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo $write_array_encode;

            exit();
          } else {
            $template_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'tb_template',
            'post_status' => 'any',
                    'numberposts' => '-1'
                );
          $template_posts = get_posts($template_args);
                foreach ( $template_posts as $template_post ) {
            $select_templates .= '<option value="'.$template_post->ID.'">'.$template_post->post_title.'</option>';
                }

            echo '<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="tb_template" />';
            echo '<select multiple="multiple" name="ids[]" size="10">'.$select_templates.'</select>';
            submit_button('Export Table Builder Templates');
            echo '</form>';

            echo "<hr />";

                $table_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'tb_table',
            'post_status' => 'any',
                    'numberposts' => '-1'
                );
                $table_posts = get_posts($table_args);
                foreach ( $table_posts as $table_post ) {
                    $select_tables .= '<option value="'.$table_post->ID.'">'.$table_post->post_title.'</option>';
                }

                echo '<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="tb_table" />';
                echo '<select multiple="multiple" name="ids[]" size="10">'.$select_tables.'</select>';
                submit_button('Export Table Builder Tables');
                echo '</form>';
          }
    }
```

Comment: What is `$this->loader`? Where is 'i15-table-builder' declared? Please post more of your code, this is an incomplete picture and it's kind of hard to help without more context.

Comment: OK, I included a link to the whole class. It is a big one. Also $this->loader is just a way to handle adding actions and filters. I can include this class as well, but I don't think it is the issue.

Comment: I edited my post with more simplified code and am still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was inside my form. Previously the name of the hidden input was post_type. I guess this messed with some stuff because after I got rid of the underscore, it worked.

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="posttype" value="tb_template" />';
```